# how to pass the value of the variable instead of the variable name in Json node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, artifactory

Hi I'm trying to do a API call using node js and when I try to use deployerID variable in JSON instead of getting test-script it is actually printing "deployerID" and thus not letting me complete the request.

```
var deployerID = "test-script";
unirest.put(permURL)
    .headers({
        'Content-Type':'application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.security.PermissionTarget+json',
        'X-JFrog-Art-Api' : api,
        sendImmediately: true
    }).send({
    "name": PermTargetName,
    "includesPattern": include,
    "excludesPattern": "",
    "repositories": [ "test-xyz" ],
    "principals": {
        "users" : {
            deployerID : ["r","w","n"]
        }
    }

})
```

Can some one tell me how to pass the value of the variable deployerID instead of "deployerID"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the variable you want to use with square brackets within the JSON. This should then parse it as a variable.

`deployerID : ["r","w","n"]`

*to*

`[deployerID]: ["r","w","n"]`

---

As per the comment by jfriend00 - This is ES6 syntax so requires a more up-to-date version of node.js (v5 <) and is referred to as a "computer property name".

Comment: You might want to add that this is ES6 syntax so it requires a newish version of node.js (greater than node v5).  It's referred to as a "computed property name".  The OP can see it described [here](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Comment: Also, it's not JSON, but rather a javascript object.

Comment: @BillyMoon - JSON == JavaScript Object Notation, a language/syntax to help define JavaScript objects as its original purpose. Technically what he has in send as a parameter is JSON.